# PL-08N inductive sensor not turning off

Tags: bed-leveling, inductive-sensor

I have one of these inductive sensors marked as `PL-08N` which should work within a `4-30 VDC` range and trigger at 8 mm or less. It's clearly a knockoff, meaning it has no manufacturer marking and all info is printed on a sticker.

[image]

I'm testing it's functionality so I tried to wire `12 V` to *brown*, `GND` to *blue* and I'm probing the *black* wire, but I'm experiencing a weird behaviour: the sensor properly triggers, but it doesn't recover, meaning the LED won't turn off moving the sensor away from the plate and the black wire doesn't go back to `0 V`.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

Looking for solutions I tried to run the device at `5 V` (still within the declared range) expecting to have a very low sensitivity, just to discover:

1. it activates at about 8 mm from the print bed (4 mm from my borosilicate glass)
2. it properly recovers immediately after I move it away

I thought those devices had increased sensitivity with greater voltages...

Comment: You seem to have connected it correctly, indeed strange behavior. Once you remove a metal object the sensor should react on the change immediately. Could be a defective sensor.

Comment: your later observation is interesting, but it might be how the device itself is set up: some devices are rated for a range and internally have some sort of regulator that results in actually just using a certain voltage, making them useable in a wider variety of systems.

Comment: @Trish I fail to get how an internal regulator would cause the output to latch on activation when the supply gets higher well within the declared range... I mean, I'm not even getting close to the maximum allowed 30 V